# WordPress custom CSS by link

Tags: css, wordpress

I am a basic WordPress website developer. Due to this I have to do custom css on many client websites.

**My question is that**, *is it possible to place any code into WordPress CSS, Which load my custom css from any code host like GitHub instead of writing CSS on WordPress custom css. *

*Reason: after giving our code to show my work some clients just run away. *

Question clarification: i want to add custom CSS for WordPress website, but don't want to use WordPress custom CSS. I want it load like bootstraps. Mean i want to host it anywhere else and load remotely.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use below function by adding it in functions.php file use that remote url by replacing bootstrap url <br>
function theme_add_custom_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_custom_css' );
```